# How to display "the" Assistant Editor?

Tags: xcode

https://web.archive.org/web/20110604185120/http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/05_ConfiguringView.html

> To add an action for the button . . .
>
> 1. In Xcode, select the view controller’s nib file (MyViewController.xib).
> 2. Display the Assistant editor.
> 3. Make sure Assistant displays the view controller’s header file (MyViewController.h).
> 4. Control drag from the button in the nib file to the method declaration area in the header file.

How to do step 2?

How to display "the" Assistant Editor?

Comment: The documentation has later been updated to read: ["_In the Xcode toolbar, click the Utilities button to hide the utilities area and click the Assistant Editor button to display the assistant editor pane.

The Assistant Editor button is the middle Editor button and it looks like this: image: ../Art/assistant_editor_button.jpg._"](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS-Legacy/chapters/RM_YourFirstApp_iOS/Articles/05_ConfiguringView.html)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's exclusive to Xcode 4:

[image: assistant editor]

Comment: You can also use the key combo ⌥+⌘+enter

Comment: I have Xcode 4.5.2 and the toolbar was hidden - that button wasn't even there. I accidentally right-clicked the top bar and saw that I could show icons or icons+text.

Answer (score 11):

In Xcode 6

[image]

It is the second button with two circles.

Comment: I tried just now. Dragging is not allowed there either.

Comment: You can still drag. For example, to drag a Webview, you can do this : hold down the ctrl while dragging with left mouse button or you can just drag to the assistant code window with right mouse button. (Yes you drag to code window and it then generates the related code).

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: As of the latest version of Xcode this has changed.

<s>In XCode 6.2 it seems they've changed the icons again. I was having trouble finding it but I didn't realize where the buttons were until the dumb old me trying to pick up iOS thought I was missing a view, so here I am posting this for any passerby who needs some visual confirmation.</s>

To be fair, I was looking for something based of some instructions I had read that referenced the two circles, and it didn't occur to me that two circles meant a split view / assistant editor, and not until after finding this post and figuring it out did I realize a suit was a reference to a butler AKA assistant :D

[image: xcode 6.2 assistant editor]

Comment: This is what I get for not touching xCode in 3 years. Believe it or not this comment had over 10 upvotes a few years ago xD Commenting the edit, thank you.