# How can I have the right ViewController class for the View while I am using Xcode?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

When I click a different ViewController in the MainStoryboard I would like to have automatically the right ViewController custom class in the other part of the screen. How can I fix this problem in Xcode?

Comment: Use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624972/how-to-display-the-assistant-editor + Select Automatic in the editor?

Answer (score 0):

When you are in the Assistant Editor, make sure the drop down has automatic chosen:

> [image]

---

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

You should assign your custom class that you have created, in Storyboard. Choose you viewcontroller and type class in the field like shown on screenshot below.
[image]